# Visual Studio find and replace right square bracket ] in character class

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a negated character class to match a square bracket tag like this *[square bracket tag]*.  The problem is, the ] character ends the character class!

I tried

```
\[[^\]]+]
```

but I get a syntax error when I run it.  (This is in the find and replace regex engine which is slightly different than the standard .NET engine fyi).

Comment: Does it work if you put it like `\[[^(])]+]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape the final end bracket:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) uses `\\` for escaping the `\` which then escapes the `.`. So you should do something like `\\[[^\\]]+\\]` and also as Damien_The_Unbeliever said you haven't closed the final bracket.

Answer (score -1):

I definitely expected escaping with "\" but it didn't work for me (grep@MacOS) but this: 
`[^]]` 
did the job.
Just place ] as the first character in class.
I actually used something like: 
`[^]?[]`