# How to include a right square bracket in a character class in R?

Tags: r, regex

This is addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399483/when-punct-is-too-much) question and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427563/how-to-include-right-bracket-in-a-character-class) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255709/r-regex-remove-all-punctuation-except-apostrophe) question is also cited), but none of them actually answer the question -- the answer provided to the first question sidesteps the issue. The more general regex answer doesn't appear to work in R:

```
gsub('[\\]`]', '', '`]')
# [1] "`]"
```

I'm trying to match a specific set of punctuation so `[:punct:]` is too general.

Comment: There's a certain order of presence. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041265/how-to-escape-closed-bracket-in-regex-in-r/32041328#32041328

Comment: Just `gsub('[]]', '', '\`]')` works, no?

Comment: @alistaire it does for this string, but no. That's just matching `]` -- the character class is `[]`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Are you sure about that?  Then why does this _fail_: `gsub('[]', '', '``]')` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen interesting

Comment: @MichaelChirico So maybe my answer _was_ working.  Let me test it a bit to try and prove it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when I was trying that myself, the string that it was failing on was: `-.,'\`<\"6\/]`

Comment: This works: `gsub('[]a\`]', '', '\`]a')` which seems to indicate the whole thing must be the class.

Comment: [This reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) says that regex implementations can be inconsistent about whether `[]]` works as a character class, it probably warrants  careful testing.

Answer (score 2):

The right bracket inside the character class appear to be work for me *unescaped*, i.e. just use this:

```
gsub('[]`]', '', '`]')
[1] ""
```

It appears that the R interpreter "knows" that a right or left bracket inside a balanced character class (i.e. consisting of a proper left bracket and right bracket) is actually just a character.

Here is proof of this claim:

```
gsub('[]a-z`]', '', '`]abc')
[1] ""
```

If the first `[]` were a closed and empty character class, then the range `a-z` should not have worked, and the letters `b` and `c` should have remained untouched.

Also: If we try to substitute using an empty character class, we get an error, e.g.

```
gsub('[]', '', '`]')
Error in gsub("[]", "", "`]") : 
  invalid regular expression '[]', reason 'Missing ']''
```

Comment: no, the character class is then just `[]`, and then it matches `\`]` directly, so this won't work on the string `\` ]`, for example

Comment: @hwnd Sorry, I didn't read the link and also you aren't Akrun, so I wasn't particularly scared either :-)  If this is a duplicate you should close it then.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the bracket and other special chars, e.g.,

```
gsub("\\]\\`", "", "]`")
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the character class problem.